# Cakephp html link with image + text, without using css

Tags: cakephp

How can I create html link that has text and image both using cakephp Html helper as below

```
<a href="#">
    <img src="images/icons/web-app/48/add-user.png" width="48" height="48"> Add User
</a>
```

I want final result as

[image]

I know that I can do that with css, but I just want to know how is it possible using cakephp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->image('design/unige_logo.png', array('width' => '48', 'height' => '48')) . ' ' . __('Add user'),
                       '#',
                       array('escape' => false));
```

Comment: @nIco sir what if the text is first before the image?

Comment: @SOS then just swap the text and the image on the first line

Comment: @niCo I tried to swap it but it prompts a syntax error, can you elaborate swap?