# unable to get image with link in cakephp 2.x?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.x

I tried to made image with link using FormHelper..in cakephp. Below are my script:

```
<?php 
    echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->image('images/view-more-arrow.png') . ' ' . __('View More'),array('controller' => 'zones', 'action' => 'index'), array('escape' => false));
?>
```

**Output:**

```
<a href="/project_folder/trunk/zones"><img src="/project_folder/trunk/img/images/view-more-arrow.png" alt=""> View More</a>
```

**Expect:**

```
 <a href="/project_folder/trunk/zones"><img src="/project_folder/trunk/images/view-more-arrow.png" alt=""> View More</a>
```

My image directory path is project_folder/app/webroot/images. I don't know why its take img/ automatic.

Thank you in Advance..

I refereed this link: 
[Cakephp html link with image + text, without using css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13682616/cakephp-html-link-with-image-text-without-using-css)

Comment: Thanks dude........I am also facing this problem.Now I got it solutions.Now onwards I will use in this way....:)

Comment: Thank to @enrmarc.....to give suggestion

Comment: Try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/q/13682616/1868660

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the slash at the beginning of the path because is relative to the app/webroot directory:

```
echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->image('/images/view-more-arrow.png') . ' ' . __('View More'),array('controller' => 'zones', 'action' => 'index'), array('escape' => false));
```

Comment: @Ayesha, Pankaj Kumar Jha,  glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this, it works perfectly for me.

```
$hd = $this->Html->image('hd.jpg',array('alt'=>'harley Davidson', 'border'=>'0', 'width'=>'450', 'height'=>'250'));
echo $this->Html->link($hd,array('controller'=>'Posts', 'action'=>'add'), array('escape'=>false));
```

Here in `$hd`, I define the path for the image and then I use this for to make link.